# jQuery Masonry Help - Filters

Tags: jquery, filter, indexing

I would really appreciate it if someone could lend some help with this.

I have a question in regard to jQuery Masonry. I am working with 6 filters for the menu (ABOUT US - PROJECTS - SERVICES - WE LIKE - All - CONTACT)

Currently, by default the homepage/index displays all of the content until a filter is clicked. Is there a way to make one of the filters (other than All) a default for the homepage/index instead of opening all of the content.

Answer (score 5):

I made jQuery Masonry.

Filtering with jQuery Masonry is now unsupported. In its stead, you can use [Isotope](http://metafizzy.co/blog/isotope-video-preview) - which does filtering a lot easier than Masonry. For example:

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.filter-class' });
```

Isotope will be released in the next couple days.

Comment: Hi, thank you Desandro. I saw the demo & isotope does look excellent..great job. However, I am currently using a masonry script and rather than starting from scratch and losing much time on this project, is there an easy solution to default the homepage/index to display specific content? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your best bet is to use the hashes technique. See [Masonry docs - filtering hashes](http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/filtering-hashes.html#red)

Comment: I used the hash technique last week, but with poor results. Perhaps my implementation was not correct. I could provide the revised script for you to look at to diagnose what went wrong. If you could, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've set up a service - [Metafizzy Support License](http://metafizzy.co/#support-license) - so users like yourself can get purchase my eyes and brain for a couple hours to help them with their code.

Comment: Very good! In that case I will be speaking with you tomorrow. Thanks again.